# node.js module.exports returns with undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is my `node.js`

```
module.exports = function(){

   console.log('hello');

}
```

In the `index.js`

```
console.log(require('./node')());
```

**Output**

```
hello
undefined
```

Why i am getting an `undefined` after the function call??

Comment: because your function doesn't return anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function doesn't return anything, it just logs to the standard output.

What really happens is that:

```
console.log(require('./node')()); // our original code

console.log((function(){console.log("hello")})()); // function runs, prints "hello"

console.log(); // nothing is returned by the function, so it prints "undefined"
```

Try changing your function to:

```
module.exports = function(){
   console.log('hello');

   return "HERE BE DRAGONS"
}
```

to see what I mean :)